# About the Lorentz transformation in Spacetime and Geometry

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, inertial-frames, notation

In Spacetime and Geometry by Sean Carroll, page 18, he said

> "We will therefore introduce a somewhat subtle notation, by using the same symbol for both matrices, just with primed and unprimed indices switched. That is, the Lorentz transformation specified by ${\Lambda^{\mu '}}_{\nu}$ has an inverse transformation written as ${\Lambda^{\rho }}_{\sigma'}$. Operationally this implies ${\Lambda^{\mu }}_{\nu'}{\Lambda^{\nu '}}_{\rho}=\delta^{\mu}_{\rho}.$"

I have systematically learned about special relativity before and this really confuses me. Shouldn't the inverse of Lorentz transformation be like $\Lambda^{-1}=\eta\Lambda^{T}\eta$ ? Is me misunderstanding things  or this book defines the inverse transformation in a weird way?

Comment: Related : [Show that any proper homogeneous Lorentz transformation may be expressed as the product of a boost times a rotation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/588883/show-that-any-proper-homogeneous-lorentz-transformation-may-be-expressed-as-the/615778#615778), equation (A-16) in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The effect of general coordinate transformation (passive point of view), or diffeomorphism (active point of view) can be written as
$$
g^{\mu' \nu'} = \Lambda^{\mu'}_{\;\alpha}\Lambda^{\nu'}_{\;\beta} g^{\alpha\beta}
$$
Multiplying left and right hand by $g_{\lambda'\mu'}$
$$
\delta_{\lambda'}^{\;\nu'} = \Lambda_{\lambda'}^{\;\beta} \Lambda^{\nu'}_{\;\beta}
$$
So,
$$
\Lambda_{\lambda'}^{\;\beta} = \left(\Lambda^{-1}\right)^{\beta}_{\;\lambda'}
$$

For the specific case that $\Lambda$ is a Lorentz transformation (which actis on flat spacetime) then
$$
g^{\mu' \nu'} = g^{\mu \nu}
$$
and we can discard the primes altogether.