# Rotation matrix in the general expression of Lorentz transformation and its meaning

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames

In section 7.2, about the Lorentz transformations, the H. Goldstein book states that given two inertial frames with a relative velocity $\textbf{v}$, the Lorentz transformation associated is given by the matrix $\textbf{L}$, where this matrix is said to be a proper transformation (see the subsection "Proper transformations" of the "Mathematical formulation" in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation) for the explicit expression of $\textbf{L}$).

In the next page, however, it also states that the most general Lorentz transformation is given by the product $\textbf{RL}$ where $\textbf{R}$ is a rotation matrix.

What does this matrix represent? I guess it's a change of basis, but I am not quite sure.

Comment: Related : [Show that any proper homogeneous Lorentz transformation may be expressed as the product of a boost times a rotation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/588883/show-that-any-proper-homogeneous-lorentz-transformation-may-be-expressed-as-the/615778#615778).

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbf{R}$ is an orthonormal rotation matrix transforming
from $xyz$ coordinates to $x'y'z'$ coordinates (as in Goldstein's chapter 4).

[image]
(image from Goldstein "Classical Mechanics")

The only thing needed be added here because of relativity
is an additional row/column for the time coordinate $ct$.
So the matrix becomes:
$$\mathbf{R}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & R_{xx} & R_{xy} & R_{xz} \\
0 & R_{yx} & R_{yy} & R_{yz} \\
0 & R_{zx} & R_{zy} & R_{zz}
\end{pmatrix}$$
In 4-dimensional spacetime this transformation represents a spatial
rotation without affecting time.